# Tell if matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Consider the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\
1&2&3&4 \\
1&-1&2&-2 \\
0&0&1&-2
\end{pmatrix}$$
Is it diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$?

I tried to compute the eigenvalues, but I couldn't factor the characteristic polynomial. So I put it in WolframAlpha and found out it wasn't the product of linear factors. So this matrix is not even triangularizable (over $\mathbb R$). But is it possible to tell straight away that this matrix is not diagonalizable without using software or making too much calculations?

Comment: In general, I check if the multiplicity of eigenvalues corresponds to the number of eigenvectors.  Does require some calculation, though

Comment: Every matrix is triangularizable, at least if you are working over an algebraically closed field.  And I'm not sure what you mean by product of linear factors, by Gaussian elimination, every matrix is the product of elementary matrices.  However, for a quick sufficient (though not necessary) condition to test if a matrix is diagonalizable, compute $\gcd(f_A(t),f'_A(t))$, where $f_A(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.  If it is equal to $1$, then the characteristic polynomial has no repeated roots, so the minimal polynomial has none, so $A$ can be diagonalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is diagonalizable over ${\Bbb C}$ but not over ${\Bbb R}$. There are two real evals and two complex conjugated. But roots are not very nice. I think the easiest way to go is to compute the characteristic polynomial (but a computer helps): $p(s) = s^4 -3 s^2 +s^2 +10s -13$ and study this. For example, $p(s)$ and $p'(s)$ have no non-trivial common factor which implies that roots are distinct (so the matrix is diagonalizable over ${\Bbb C}$).

Comment: Yes the eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C}$ are given as: $-1.79$, $1.62$, $1.58 \pm 1.39j$. Also, the corresponding eigenvectors span $\mathbb{C}^{4}$

Comment: How do I prove that it is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @user365888 It follows from it not having all real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Lovsovs, I know that... But how do I prove it hasn't all real eigenvalues without WolframAlpha? It has a 4 degree char polynomial. I'm not able to tell that it has some non-real roots...

Comment: @user365888 Ah, sorry, my mistake!

Comment: @user365888 You may use the socalled Sturm sequence for $p$ and $p'$, cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem (see the example a bit down the page).

Answer (score 1):

First find the characteristic polynomial. Then apply [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem), which gives the number of real roots. If this is lower than the degree of the polynomial, the matrix is not diagonalizable.

The method involves some polynomial division, but you can get there without the use of software.